# Animation Nodes using 100% CPU on Linux

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to create a node tree that builds a 3D matrix of 10x10x25 spheres. With the node tree shown below my cpu is at 100% at all times. Am I asking too much of it or is there a way to reduce the drain on the processor. I am using the latest 2.79 version of Blender on Ubuntu 17.10 Thanks!

[node tree image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18alTrwLHngozLKY-3tW_86Cy6Z8bBbeI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In default settings, AN rebild scene "always", that means that AN invoke your set up as many times as it possible.

[image]

Instead of this, try the setting, whan AN will be invoke nodes only if something changed:

[image]

It's more friendly for CPU, and faster for workflow..